# error C2660: 'SurroundTheGrid' : function does not take 0 arguments

Tags: c++, arguments

Please help, having problems trying to test my programming assignment for C++. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am thinking it has something to do with my arguments in a function called SurroundTheGrid()

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Assignment 08 ADL, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 3/19/2013 12:57:34 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Creating "Debug\Assignment 08 ADL.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was   specified.
1>ClCompile:
1>  Assignment 08 ADL.cpp
1>j:\co 127\assignment 08 adl\assignment 08 adl.cpp(108): error C2660:   'SurroundTheGrid' : function does not take 0 arguments
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:12.90
```

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Sorry about no posting the code everyone, I am new at this. But here it is any help would be greatful, thank you.

```
  /*
 Anthony Lehnen
 Assignment 08 ADL
 03/12/2013
 */



 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include "student.h" // this includs student.h
 #include "COMPFUN.H"     // for decimals
 #include "GRID.H"

 extern const int east = 3;


 using namespace std;

 //************HEADER**************//
 void Heading()
 {
system("cls");
cout << "Anthony Lehnen\t"   "CO 127\t"  "02/28/2013\t"  "Assignment 07" <<           endl;
cout << endl;
cout << endl;
 }

 void display(student aStudent)
 {
  decimals(cout, 2);
  cout << "{ student: " << aStudent.name();
  cout << ", GPA = " << aStudent.GPA() << " }" << endl;
 }


 int Student()
 { // test drive student: this main will vary amongst students
student aStudent("Nguyen", 36.5, 123.5);
student anotherStudent("Stella", 4.0, 16.0);  // Straight A so far
student one("one", 0.0, 0.0); // Should be 3.0
one.completedCourse( 4.0, 2.0 );
one.completedCourse( 4.0, 4.0 );  // 4 credit A
display(one);
display(aStudent);
display(anotherStudent);

// Finish branch coverage testing of standing
student two("two", 100.0, 30.0);
student three( "three", 30.05, 100.0 );
student four("four" , 60.0, 100.0 );
student five("five ", 60.05, 100.0);
student six ("six " , 90.0, 100.0);
student seven("seven", 90.05, 100.0 );

cout << endl << endl;

cout << "Student: " << one.name() <<" is a " << one.standing() << endl;
cout << "Student: " << two.name() <<" is a " << two.standing() << endl;
cout << "Student: " << three.name() <<" is a " << three.standing() << endl;
cout << "Student: " << four.name() <<" is a " << four.standing() << endl;
cout << "Student: " << five.name() <<" is a " << five.standing() << endl;
cout << "Student: " << six.name() <<" is a " << six.standing() << endl;
cout << "Student: " << seven.name() <<" is a " << seven.standing() << endl;
cout << endl << endl;

return 0;

 }
  void SurroundTheGrid()
  {
 int r, c;

 for(r = 0; r < g.nRows(); r++)
 {
    myGrid.putDown(r, 0);
    myGrid.putDown(r, myGrid.nColumns()-1);
 }
 for(c = 1; c < myGrid.nColumns() -1; c++)
 {
    myGrid.putDown(0, c);
    myGrid.putDown(myGrid.nRows()-1, c);
 }
   }

  int TestSurroundGrid()
  {//Test drive SurroundTheGrid
  grid myGrid(4, 10, 3, 0, east);
  SurroundTheGrid(myGrid);
  myGrid.display();
  return 0;

  }



  //**********************MAIN***************************//
  int main()
  {
  Heading();
  Student();

  system("pause");
  system("CLS");

  Heading();
  SurroundTheGrid();

  system("pause");

  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: I am looking in my magic crystal ball... and I see... a function... yees, a function with some parameters... but the caller is using no arguments to invoke it... as if it was some kind of... student who doesn't even take the effort of posting his code and expects people to spend their time for free thinking about it. -1, sorry.

Comment: Post your code, that way we can tell you exactly what your problem is. The code around line 108 (where the error occurred), and the definition of the function `SurroundTheGrid` are most important, if your code is too long to post entirely.

Comment: added the code, sorry everyone, new to this.

Comment: wow i figured it out, sorry to bother you all. I appreciate the advice and help.

Comment: Is this *exactly* the code you got the error with? 'cause it still seems off. You should get a few errors, including one stating that `myGrid` is not defined in `SurroundTheGrid`. Furthermore, the code you posted actually shows a function which takes 0 arguments (although considering the `myGrid` problem it should probably take 1), and you're using it in two different places. Once with 1 argument, once with 0. Post the code which gave you the stated errors so we can fix that, OR post the errors from this code so we can fix this. Don't mix them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading error messages from your compiler is an important skill, so let's see what we can make out of this one. The specific error that you're getting is this one:

```
j:\co 127\assignment 08 adl\assignment 08 adl.cpp(108): error C2660: 'SurroundTheGrid' : function does not take 0 arguments
```

As you've correctly interpreted already, it's saying that the problem has something to do with your `SurroundTheGrid` function. However, it's not the declaration or definition of the function itself. The problem is actually in one of your *calls* to the function.

Specifically, the error message tells you that the problem is located around line 108 of the file `assignment 08 adl.cpp` (although it gives you the full path just to make the message longer).

And it's telling you that you tried to call the `SurroundTheGrid` function with no arguments, but it actually requires some arguments (I don't know the exact number, the error message doesn't say).

Presumably, what happened on line 108 is that you have something like:

```
SurroundTheGrid();        // passes no arguments to the function -- WRONG!
```

When you should have something like:

```
SurroundTheGrid(myGrid);  // pass an argument specifying the grid (or something)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't really go into details here since you didn't post your code, but your guess is right. Like the error states, you're calling the function `SurroundTheGrid` with 0 arguments (so just the parenthesis, no arguments whatsoever), but the function doesn't take 0 arguments. This means that you should provide the correct number and type of arguments (again, I can't tell you how many or what arguments, because you didn't post your code).